# invoking an angular route from angular service to load a new view and controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to invoke a route through and angular service and since I am using `$http.post` I can't get the route to invoke. I may be going at this all wrong so I'm hoping someone can make a suggestion or point me in the right direction. Initally I have a page load with a controller which once the search command is called it passes a json object with the request to an angular service which then calls webAPI to pass the request onto my other business layers. Here is a logical diagram of the workflow. The response in blue is a new data object being returned to the UI with the users search results. 
[image]

From my app I have the following routes setup

```
(function () {

    app = angular.module('app', ['ui.bootstrap', 'ngRoute', 'ngAnimate']).value('ngToastr', toastr);

    function router($routeProvider) {
            $routeProvider.
            when('/search/query', {
                templateUrl: '../../AngularTemplates/searchResults.html',
                controller: 'searchResultCtrl'
            }).
            otherwise({
                templateUrl: '../../AngularTemplates/splashPage.html'
            });
    }

    app.config(['$routeProvider', router]);

    //added toaster as factory so it can be injected into any controller
    angular.module('app').factory('ngNotifier', function (ngToastr) {
        return {
            notify: function (msg) {
                ngToastr.success(msg);
            },
            notifyError: function (msg) {
                ngToastr.error(msg);
            },
            notifyInfo: function (msg) {
                ngToastr.info(msg);
            }
        }
    });



})();
```

The initial page calls the controller which has a service dependency

```
app.controller('searchController', ['$scope', '$filter', 'searchService', 'ngNotifier', '$log', '$timeout',  'searchAttributes' , function ($scope, $filter, searchService, ngNotifier, $log, $timeout, searchAttributes) {

    var vm = this;
    vm.search = search;
    vm.updateEntities = updateEntitySelection;

    //bootstraped data from MVC
    $scope.userOptions = searchAttributes.mvcData;

    //scoped variables
    $scope.searchTerm = null;

    //ui container for search response
    $scope.searchResponse;

    $scope.entityList = [
        'Search All ',
        'Search in Departments ',
        'Search in Automotive '
    ]

    $scope.selectedEntity = 'Search All';

    function buildSearchRequest() {
        var searchResponse = {
            searchTerm: $scope.searchTerm,
            pageSize: 10,//this will be set by configuration from the UI 
            pagesReturned: 0,
            entityFilter: $scope.selectedEntity
    };
        return searchResponse;
    }

    function onError(msg) {
        $log.error('An error has occured: ' + msg.data);
    }

    function updateEntitySelection(entityName) {
        $scope.selectedEntity = entityName;
    }

    function search() {
        var request = buildSearchRequest();
        searchService.search(request);
    }

}]);
```

and the search service

```
app.factory('searchService', ['$http', function($http) {

    var myEsResults;

    function getSearchResults(searchRequest) {
        return $http.post('search/query', searchRequest, {}).then(function (response) {

        myEsResults =  response.data});
    }

    var getResults = function () {
        return myEsResults;
    };

    return{
        search: getSearchResults,
        getResults: getResults
    };
}]);
```

What I am trying to accomplish is when the document loads a splash screen is displayed (which works). when the search is executed the request is passed to webapi and then the response is returned as an objectback to the view and a new controller so it can render the search results. I have passed data back and forth between controllers in the past however where I am stuck is using an angular service to call route in webapi. Making this call does not update the page URL and therefore the route is not invoked nor is the second controller  loaded to display the results. In the past I have invoked angular routes using a url `http://#/route` however in this instance I am using an input button with `ng-click`.  I would appreciate any suggestions as to how on the return of data get the 'result view' and controller to load. Is routing the correct approach or is there another way to load the view and controller when using an angular service?

Thanks in advance

```
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" ng-click="vm.search()"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should be able to do it using `$location.path('/search/query')`

```
 function getSearchResults(searchRequest) {
    return $http.post('search/query', searchRequest, {}).then(function (response) {

        myEsResults =  response.data;
        $location.path('/search/query');
    });
}
```

however workflow seems like it would make more sense to add either `routeParams` to the url or a search query param and pass url encoded query term to url and make request based on that. Then the request would be made by the `searchResultCtrl` controller or a `resolve` in the router config.

Something like:

```
$routeProvider.
        when('/search/query/:queryterm', {
            templateUrl: '../../AngularTemplates/searchResults.html',
            controller: 'searchResultCtrl'
        }).
```

And path would be generated by:

```
$location.path('/search/query/' + encodeURIComponent($scope.searchTerm) );
```